# Show all user articles from another view in profile [django]

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have **Article model** in **news_app**

```
class Article(Created, HitCountMixin):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  
    snippet = models.TextField(null=False)
```

with view:

```
class AllArticlesListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'news/articles_list.html'
    model = Article
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
```

in another app (**user_app**) I have **Profile model**:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, default='Brak')
```

with view

```
class ProfileView(HitCountDetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile/profile.html'
```

In **project url** I have:

```
path("<slug:slug>", ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
```

and in **news_app url** I have:

```
path('all/', AllArticlesListView.as_view(), name='all_articles_list'),
```

**How can i show all user articles IN HIS USER PROFILE?**

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profile/profile.html'
    count_hit = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your articles to the context;

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """ Add the articles to the context """
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            context['articles'] = Article.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return context
```

You can find details of what's in `DetailView` and other django views here; http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

Comment: Thanks! i wil check it. There is possible make more than 1 model in context?

Comment: You can put add whatever you want really. It just returns a dictionary of things which are then accessible to your template